# How to set the background color of a ttk.Combobox

Tags: python-3.x, combobox, tkinter, background-color, ttk

I have a problem to set background color for Combobox using tkinter ttk with 'vista' theme (I'm using Python 3). I've tried code from here [ttk.Combobox glitch when state is read-only and out of focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610519/ttk-combobox-glitch-when-state-is-read-only-and-out-of-focus)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['1', '2', '3'])
combo['state'] = 'readonly'
combo.pack()
tk.Entry(root).pack()

style = ttk.Style()
style.map('TCombobox', selectbackground=[('readonly', 'red')])
#style.map('TCombobox', fieldbackground=[('readonly', 'blue')]) #not working as well
```

But this will change only background for text, rest part of combobox rests white. Also I saw a post on the tcl forum: http://wiki.tcl.tk/15780 and I've tried with 'fieldbackground' but it seems that tkinter ignores this parameter. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Maybe there is a way to configure only specific style in specific theme? I saw that for 'default' theme, the background changes to gray color if state is 'readonly'.

Comment: Your code works fine in python 2.7. You need to use `fieldbackground` only. It works as expected.

Comment: Did you try it with 'vista' theme? For this theme, it's not work for me.

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, the order you set the properties of the new *style* is important to determine if a certain property of the new style will be applied or not. For example, if I set first the `background` instead of `selectbackground`, then the color of selection will not be changed, but just the mini button color with the arrow (to list down the options).

I noted also that depending on the value of `parent`, which I suppose is the *parent style* from which the new *style* is derived, some of the new settings and properties of the new *style* might not be applied. For example, if I try to change the `fieldbackground` property when `parent` is set to `aqua`, it does not work, but if `parent` is set to `alt`, it works. (*I hope more expert users can help and contribute to improve this answer, which could be helpful also for future users of `ttk` and `tkinter`*).

This is my solution, where I created a complete new style:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

combostyle = ttk.Style()

combostyle.theme_create('combostyle', parent='alt',
                         settings = {'TCombobox':
                                     {'configure':
                                      {'selectbackground': 'blue',
                                       'fieldbackground': 'red',
                                       'background': 'green'
                                       }}}
                         )
# ATTENTION: this applies the new style 'combostyle' to all ttk.Combobox
combostyle.theme_use('combostyle') 

# show the current styles
# print(combostyle.theme_names())

combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['1', '2', '3'])
combo['state'] = 'readonly'
combo.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Since I am not an expert on `ttk`, I was not able to apply a new *theme* just to a certain instance of type `ttk.Combobox`, but I applied the *theme* to all instances of future possible `ttk.Combobox`. If someone can improve this answer, I would really appreciate the gesture!

For more information on how to create and set new styles, see [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html) or [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html).

Comment: Hi, I've tried your code and it seems to work. Unfortunately it looks like there is no possibility to change background color for let's say, 'vista' theme.

For 'winnative' you can change only background color,
for 'clam', 'alt', default', 'classic' you can change everything, with some different behaviour is combobox is focused or selected.
For 'vista' and 'xpnative' it seems not working at all

Answer (score 7):

This code below worked fine for me.It is important set the order of the parameters.

```py
style = ttk.Style()

style.map('TCombobox', fieldbackground=[('readonly','white')])
style.map('TCombobox', selectbackground=[('readonly', 'white')])
style.map('TCombobox', selectforeground=[('readonly', 'black')])

self.mycombo = ttk.Combobox(self.frame,textvariable=self.combo_var,
                            height=15,justify='left',width=21,
                            values=lista)

self.mycombo['state'] = 'readonly' # Set the state according to configure colors
self.mycombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',
                  lambda event: self._click_combo())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the color without regard to the state of the widget (ie. hover, pressed, etc...), then you will want to use the `configure` method instead of the `map` method, as the `map` method is meant specifically for applying various formats to specific widget states. Since you are only using the "readonly" state, I assume this is what you want.

```
style.configure('TCombobox', fieldbackground='red')
```

Comment: Add more details to explain your answer