# Background color of combobox selected/default value

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I wish to change default white color of tkinter combobox to orange, and on selection to color it green. I cannot find how to target full field, I can only get font color changed.

[image: image1]

I searched forums and web, but couldn't find solution anywhere.
I managed to color Listbox to orange, but not default value.

[image: image2]

Listbox background

```
window.option_add("*TCombobox*Listbox*Background", 'orange')
```

My Combobox style

```
ttk.Style().layout('combostyleO.TCombobox')
ttk.Style().configure('combostyleO.TCombobox', selectforeground='black', selectbackground='orange', background='green', foreground='orange', padding=4)
```

Combobox creation

```
lendersR = StringVar(window)
lendersR.set('Select lender')  # set the default option
choicesR = excel.Excel().get_resi_lenders_from_csv()
choicesR = sorted(choicesR)
lenderMenuR = ttk.Combobox(window, width=55, height=30, font="Courier 10", textvariable=lendersR, values=choicesR, style="combostyleO.TCombobox")
```

Comment: I think that here there is what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912250/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-ttk-combobox

Comment: thank you for this, it solved half of my problem. I applied style to all my combobox in app (there are 3). 
Now I need to apply green color only on combo that I changed, not to all of them. any idea how to do it?

Comment: Part of solution
combostyle = ttk.Style()
combostyle.theme_create('combostyle', parent='alt',settings = {'TCombobox':
                                     {'configure':
                                      {'selectbackground': 'orange',
                                       'fieldbackground': 'orange',
                                       'background': 'orange',
                                       }}}
                         )
combostyle.theme_use('combostyle')