# How can i change the background and foreground color for ttk combo boxes?

Tags: python, tkinter

Does anyone have any insight on this? I already made a style for the notebook background so i tried doing the same with the combo box brackground but it doesnt work. This is what i have.

```
combostyle = ttk.Style()

combostyle.theme_create('custom_style',
                   parent='alt',
                   settings={'TCombobox':
                             {'configure':
                              {'selectforeground': 'white',
                               'selectbackground': '#1a2228',
                               'fieldforeground': 'white',
                               'fieldbackground': '#1a2228',
                               'background': '#1a2228'
                               }
                              }
                             }
                   )
combostyle.theme_use('custom_style')

root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*Background', '#1a2228')
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*Foreground', 'white')
```

**SCREENSHOTS**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have posted is related to defining a new theme by configuring the `ttk Combobox` widget and using the same for your GUI.

I have posted the following code taking a similar approach to create a simple `ttk Combobox` with custom background and foreground color styles.

I have tested this with the `default` and `alt` parent themes.

The ttk combobox popdown listbox cannot be configured using `ttk style` nor
via the widget `configure` command. The listbox can be configured using the
`option`  database. Read more about this [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm)

I'm using `Python 3.7`, `Tcl/Tk 8.6` on `Windows`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

window = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
# creating a custom theme
style.theme_create('custom_style',
                   parent='alt',
                   settings={'TCombobox':
                             {'configure':
                              {'selectforeground': 'blue',
                               'selectbackground': 'yellow',
                               'fieldforeground': 'blue',
                               'fieldbackground': 'yellow',
                               'background':'yellow'
                               }
                              }
                             }
                   )
style.theme_use('custom_style')

# following are style option for the drop down combobox listbox
window.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*Background', 'blue')
window.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox*Foreground', 'yellow')

values = ['CS', 'EC', 'ME']
select_branch = ttk.Combobox(window, values=values, width=15, state='readonly')
select_branch.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

**Screenshots**

[image: s1]

[image: s2]

[image: s3]

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey this works for only the drop down options, the main color on it still doesnt change from white...

Comment: Hey @mferraro, ok,.. Try by changing `parent='alt'` to `parent='default'` in the `custom_style`

Comment: still nothing. hope my updated code helps tho

Answer (score 0):

This topic has been discussed and solved in this Question here: [Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912250/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-ttk-combobox) 
Just have a look, it should clear any questions.

Comment: what is the downvote for?

Comment: Because if this is a duplicate, then you should mark to close as a duplicate or comment it. Not post an answer