# Combobox changing out of focus background and foreground color

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

I need to change the foreground and background colour of combobox input field when it is not in focus. I read through these [this](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/options.html) and [this](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Changing+Widget+Colors) but am not able to figure out which one to use.

I am using Python 3.9.6 on Windows 10.

Here is a sample code.

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK

objWindow = objTK.Tk()

objStyle = objTTK.Style()
objStyle.theme_use("clam")
objStyle.configure("TCombobox", backgroundcolor="orange")
objStyle.configure("TCombobox", foregroundcolor="blue")

tMonths = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
cbDtRStM = objTTK.Combobox(master=objWindow, width=10, state="readonly", values=tMonths)
cbDtRStM.pack()

btnButton = objTTK.Button(master=objWindow, text="Test")
btnButton.pack()

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda funcWinSum: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```

Currently the text is displayed as grayed out as in picture below.

[image: Picture]

I would like to make the text as black with background as white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18610519/ttk-combobox-glitch-when-state-is-read-only-and-out-of-focus)

Here is the updated code.

```
import tkinter as objTK
from tkinter import ttk as objTTK

objWindow = objTK.Tk()

objStyle = objTTK.Style()
objStyle.theme_use("clam")
objStyle.map("TCombobox", selectforeground=[('readonly', '!focus', 'black')], \
            selectbackground=[('readonly', '!focus', '#DCDAD5')])
tMonths = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
cbDtRStM = objTTK.Combobox(master=objWindow, width=10, state="readonly", values=tMonths)
cbDtRStM.pack()

btnButton = objTTK.Button(master=objWindow, text="Test")
btnButton.pack()

objWindow.bind("<Escape>", lambda funcWinSum: objWindow.destroy())

objWindow.mainloop()
```